# CSS solution equal height 2 columns where smaller column wins?

Tags: css

I have two columns. A sidebar with a long navigation and main content. The sidebar will always have more height than the main content. I want the sidebar to have the equal height to the main column. The sidebar will have `overflow-y: scroll` and should not be higher than the main content. I can not use `height` or `max-height` as the content of the main content will vary and therefore I do not know the height.

I was hoping to find a solution with the new CSS Grid but I have not really figured it out.

*Note I am aware that this can be achieved relatively easy with a script but am hoping to find a CSS solution to this.*

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ingvi/4kxxsjwa/14/)

Comment: It is unclear to me what your intention is. Do you need the sidebar and main content to be both `100%` of the page height with overflow of contents? What have you tried so far? Perhaps an image or code snippet could be helpful. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: There is a link at the bottom of my question. 
The main content should determine the height of the sidebar. I hope that clarifies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```
aside {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

ul {
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4kxxsjwa/19/